# Get tag when implementing JSON Marshaler interface

Tags: go

How do we get the tag information when implementing the JSON marshaler interface when marshaling the Foo instance below? Note that we can also have a Bar struct which also uses MyNullString. So we cannot assume MyNullString is being used only by Foo struct.

package main

```
import (
  "fmt"
  "database/sql"
  "encoding/json"
)
type MyNullString struct {
   sql.NullString
}

type Foo struct {
    MyInt int64
    MyString MyNullString `json:"my_string,omitempty"` 
}

func (s *MyNullString) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error){
    //Inspect tag of struct instance and see if this field has to be omitted when empty
    //HOW?????
    //Note: We can use MyNullString in other structs as well. 
}

func main(){
   foo := Foo{MyInt: 1}
   data, _ := json.Marshal(&foo)
   fmt.Println(string(data))
}
```

Comment: Check out the `reflect` package and especially examples of extracting `StructField` from structs. You can read the json implementation and see what they did. It's pretty simple.

Comment: You will have to implement `MarshalJSON` on the struct itself I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible for a type to inspect other types/values that contain it (you can't see the box you're in, but you can see the boxes in you). There is an open feature request for custom omitempty support, such that a type can inform the encoder that it's an "empty" value, but there's nothing usable at this time. See http://golang.org/issue/4357

Comment: Well! I guess we have to wait till then.